# UV Coordinates of "curve" (or "bend")

Tags: textures, uv-mapping

I am looking for some tutorial or equation how to map texture from square to "curve" or "bend". (Example on image below) I have tried to convert coordinates of unit circle to UV, but that gives me incorrect result around corners.

[image]

Comment: Do you have an example of the wrapping you would like to achieve?

Comment: @SethBattin No.. but I wan to map simple road texture (black, with white line in the middle). So far I am trying mapping with UV test texture, but I got got result in the middle of the curve, but closer to the one end, texture is more and more stretched

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you just need plain rectangular UV coordinates.  The inner radius is `V = 1`, and the outer radius is `V = 0`.  That angular procession from the bottom up is from `U = 1` to `U = 0` (or the opposite depending on tech).  The vertex locations can be arranged in a curve, but the texture coordinates don't have to be.

[image: uv coords]
[image: position coords]

Comment: Thats is what I am doing. But I have wrong inner radius (0.5) and outer (1.0). Thanks.

Comment: Great answer, but what is up with the stylish jaggies?

Comment: @bobobobo My art prowess grows every time I open GIMP.